# Do axial displacement experiments under hydrostatic load scale linearly to any size?

Tags: pressure, deflection, hydrostatics

In J. D. Stachiw's book *Acrylic plastic viewports for ocean engineering applications* [[PDF]](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.31822009085754&view=1up&seq=337) on page 337 it includes a Figure 7.12 [[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q1Og.png)] showing the results of applying hydrostatic loads to an acrylic window 2.25 inches wide over a 1.5 inch hole in a flange.

The results show the deflection for a range of pressures, and are indicated for various t/Di (thickness / inner diameter). Does t/Di being unitless imply that these experimental results are linearly scalable to any window size? For example, can I just replace all inches with centimeters and an experiment would give similar centimeter displacements (for a given psi)? Can I multiply both the window thickness and flange hole by 10x and get the same results with 10x displacement? Would the psi pressure Y-axis remain the same or does that need to be scaled too?

[image: Figure 7.12]

Stachiw, J. D, Acrylic plastic viewports for ocean engineering applications, San Diego, Calif. : Naval Undersea Center, 1977

Comment: if you replace inches with centimeters, won't you replace psi with N/mm^2 ?

Comment: It also depends on mounting conditions and age, which can vary: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Figure-Principal-stress-s-r-at-the-centre-of-minor-diameter-varying-from-t-D-i_fig15_311242867

Answer (score 0):

You can scale within the range of values that they tested for. You should consider that they chose that tested range as being related or controlled byt he design parameters that they considered.

BUT, once you go outside of those ranges then the behaviour may change. Which means if you are to increase the pressure range by a factor of 10 for example you may exceed material limits etc and get a catastrophic failure which is outside the tested range.